# Prefill user data just after download and first launch iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, url, app-store, mobile-safari

User downloads my iPhone app from the appStore link I provide from invite email. Is it possible to persist/cache the user-data say email Address and pre-fill when the app launched.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this can't be done. Your special link might take the user to the app store, but then that's it. The act of installing the app has nothing to do with your link anymore and no data can be passed to the freshly installed app.

Of course once the app is installed, if the user taps on a special link you provide, it could force your app to run and provide data to it.

Maybe you could provide a QR code the use can scan with your app the first time they run it. The QR code can contain the data you want. Of course the user may choose to not scan the code. Then again, the user can install your app without using your link to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

You can get all the data that Apple allows you to get, which is absolutely none - you can't get the user's email, you can't get his phone number, you can't get his UDID. No way to identify him. If you want anything from the user, he needs to enter it manually. If you think about it - it's actually a good thing. All your iphone information is completely secure and protected.